# How do I install ASP.NET 5 vNext on Mac OS X? 404 on mono--monolite

Tags: osx-yosemite, asp.net-core

I tried to install the latest ASP.NET on Mac OS X Yosemite according to the instructions on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/home).

I already have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), so this step worked fine:

```
brew tap aspnet/k
```

However, on the next step, `brew install kvm`, I get errors:

```
$ brew install kvm
==> Installing kvm dependency: mono
==> Downloading http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.8.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mono-3.8.0.tar.bz2
==> Downloading http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "mono--monolite"
Download failed: http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz
```

Note: the first time I ran this, I got a slightly different message when `mono-3.8.0` installed successfully.

David Fowler was quick to answer my question on Twitter and suggested a `brew update` (Thanks David!) but I got this:

```
$ brew update
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Formula/google-perftools.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

At this point, it seems like it's a Homebrew problem. What am I doing wrong?

---

Update: sorry, I was an idiot. As suggested by agua from mars and David Folwer, I fixed the issue as follows:

```
cd /usr/local/Library/Formula/
git reset HEAD google-perftools.rb
git checkout google-perftools.rb
brew update
brew install kvm
```

And this time kvm installed OK. Then I just added the line `source /usr/local/Cellar/kvm/1.0.0-beta1/libexec/kvm.sh` to my .bash_profile

Comment: you have a git conflict on this file Library/Formula/google-perftools.rb. you should undo your change: git checkout -- Library/Formula/google-perftools.rb

Comment: Thanks @aguafrommars - I was so stupid, should have tried to figure out where the brew formula git repo was before posting the question :-) After doing a git reset and `brew update`, the monolite install worked fine! Feel free to answer if you want and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discuss in comments.

You have a git conflict on this file Library/Formula/google-perftools.rb.

you should undo your change:

```
git checkout -- Library/Formula/google-perftools.rb
```

or doing a git reset.

And update brew again